# Biasing an Operational Amplifier

Tags: cmos

Consider a simple two stage CMOS operational amplifier. When it's designed for given specification and is being used as an Op-amp block, doesn't its bias gets disturbed when any arbitrary voltage is applied to inputs by the user?

Say if one of the terminals is grounded, wouldn't the differential amplifier inside be off?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of op amp you have drawn would certainly be unable to properly operate at the most negative end of the power rails. This is why a lot of op amp applications use a proper negative rail hence 0 volts (ground) is somewhere close to the midpoint between supplies.

The circuit you have drawn would work with inputs close to (or slightly above) the positive rail of course but. if you want an op-amp that can operate with inputs across the whole supply range you need a far more complex input circuit.

If you look at this BJT op amp you can see the complexity: -

[image]

There are two diff input pairs - one formed by Q1 and Q2 and another formed by Q3 and Q4 - at somewhere mid supply one pair takes over from the other pair thus allowing the full input range to be resolved. Note that the circuit above is also rail-to-rail output too. The diagram is of an LT6220

Comment: Thanks. But isn't it necessary for the differential pair to have a DC bias? Users could apply any voltage to the inputs +IN and -IN (within the ICMR) without knowing the internal circuitry. If there is no DC bias given to differential pair, they might not operate in saturation region(MOSFETS) or active region(BJTs).

Comment: The DC bias comes from the input signals for absolutely every op-amp ever created.

Comment: What if the input is a very small signal(Like a sensor output in mV)? How do you expect the mosfets to be biased properly?

Comment: @AdityaPatil The supplies of an op-amp for that sort of application will normally be +/- X volts relative to 0V. The sensor output might be at 0V for no output signal therefore the op-amp is appropriately biased exactly half way between + and - outputs. It sounds like you need to be doing rudimentary research about op-amps before jumping into the make-up of an op-amp.

Comment: Thanks. I am studying basics of analog integrated circuits and two stage opamp design is one of my projects. Could you please explain me how the transistors m1 and m2(in my diagram) will be biased, if signal is directly applied to the terminals vip and vim?

Comment: The DC level on both signals has to be somewhere around mid-rail between gnd and Vdd.